# Karate 0.9.1 - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: karate

When I'm trying to run *.feature file or a single scenario with "right-click" (IntelliJ Idea), I've always received an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:457)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:347)
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:162)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:154)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject$KeyIterator.init(ScriptObject.java:2467)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject$ScriptObjectIterator.hasNext(ScriptObject.java:2441)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror$13.call(ScriptObjectMirror.java:368)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror$13.call(ScriptObjectMirror.java:363)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.inGlobal(ScriptObjectMirror.java:858)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.entrySet(ScriptObjectMirror.java:363)
    at net.minidev.json.reader.JsonWriter$7.writeJSONString(JsonWriter.java:135)
    at net.minidev.json.reader.JsonWriter$7.writeJSONString(JsonWriter.java:128)
    at com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils$NashornObjectJsonWriter.writeJSONString(JsonUtils.java:77)
    at com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils$NashornObjectJsonWriter.writeJSONString(JsonUtils.java:67)
...
```

Same scenario works fine if I run with TestRunner.java. Looks like that problem is in IJ cucumber plugin. 
Maybe someone has a solution or workaround for this issue.

I'm using karate 0.9.1, cucumber for Java plugin: v183.4284.148, Idea 2018.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has reported this - and from the stack-trace it looks like some JSON that you are using is being printed to the console - has some circular references, maybe you are using a Map of object references. But yes I can't explain why this works fine in the runner.

Can you follow the instructions here and submit a sample project, we can try open it in IntelliJ: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: this was a cyclic reference, but we have [fixed it to be safe in future](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/658#issuecomment-457898258).